# How to unzip file, change csv table, and zip again?

Tags: r, csv, zip, unzip

I have a lot a .zip files. I need to:

- Open zip file
- Edit .csv table in it
- Zip file again with same name as the beginning

It is possible in R? For many files it is quite a difficult task, because it is large dataset and I need to process in sequence. Besides the .csv file, there are a few other files in each zip folder.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in R. If you can do it with one file, the number of files is no issue as you can use a simple loop. I'd use package data.table (in particular the functions `fread` and `fwrite`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unzip` and `zip` functions. In an `lapply` loop, we first create a `tempfile` which is used to `unzip` and which we can `read.csv`. We identify the .csv with `grep`. Then edit and reverse the process. Only the .csv gets updated, the other files are untouched.

```
toEdit <- c("df1.zip", "df2.zip", "df3.zip")

lapply(toEdit, function(z) {
  temp <- tempfile()
  temp <- unzip(z)
  r <- read.csv(temp[grep("csv", temp)])
  ## edit data
  r <- r/10
  ## end edit data
  nn <- gsub("zip", "csv", z)
  write.csv(r, nn)
  zip(z, nn)
  unlink(temp)
})
```

---

*Example data:*

Creating .zip archives with one .csv file and some other stuff in it.

```
write("foo", "xy1.foo")
write("foo", "xy2.foo")
sapply(1:3, function(i) {
  write.csv(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), paste0("df", i, ".csv"))
  zip(paste0("df", i, ".zip"), paste0("df", i, ".csv"))
  zip(paste0("df", i, ".zip"), "xy1.foo")
  zip(paste0("df", i, ".zip"), "xy2.foo")
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have few questions: 
- in the case of example data, no zip files are created, but only .csv
- how to quicker get list files rather than 'toEdit <- c("df1.zip", "df2.zip", "df3.zip")'?

Comment: Yet I noticed that the csv table that is being edited appears separately in the work path and the table in the zip folder is unchanged. I need to edit the table in the zip folder and save it back to this folder.

Comment: @Nicolas You may use `dir`, try `toEdit <- dir("V:/zips/")[grep(".zip$", dir("V:/zips/"))]`, where `"V:/zips/"` is your path.